# HackerRank says ~ no response on stdout ~

Tags: java, output, stdout

So I was solving this Question on HackerRank (Project Euler Q1) [link here](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001), and have used the following code to solve it

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */

    int T = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> N = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String[] Input = args;
    if  (args.length>1){
        T = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        if(T<1||T>Math.pow(10,6))
            System.exit(0);
    }
    if (args.length-1 == T){
        for (int i=1;i<args.length;i++){
            N.add(Integer.parseInt(args[i]));
            int sum3=0,sum5=0,sum15=0;
            int count=0;
            while (count<N.get(i-1)){
                sum3+=count;
                count+=3;
            }
            count =0;
            while (count<N.get(i-1)){
                sum5+=count;
                count+=5;
            }
            count =0;
            while (count<N.get(i-1)){
                sum15+=count;
                count+=15;
            }
            N.set(i-1,(sum3+sum5-sum15));
        }
    }
    for(int j=0;j<N.size();j++)
        System.out.println(N.get(j));
    }
}
```

This gives me the following output on an IDE :

```
23
2318
```

While Inputting :

```
2
10
100
```

And this matches the expected output on HackerRank, but however When I use this code on the website, It says :

Input (stdin)

```
2
10
100
```

Your Output (stdout)

```
~ no response on stdout ~
```

Expected Output

```
23
2318
```

Compiler Message

```
Wrong Answer
```

One thing I could observe was I couldn't print anything from inside a loop on HackerRank. What would the solution to this be?

Comment: You're getting your arguments via `args` (command line arguments) instead of STDIN (standard input).

Answer (score 1):

You're not reading from STDIN the way HackerRank wants you to. Instead of getting your input from args, you should be doing this kind of thing:

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int numberOfTestCases = sc.nextInt();
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this code, compiled fine and submitted it.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Solution{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException   
   {

        //Input
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int[] N = new int[T];
        for(int t = 0; t < T; N[t++] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())){
        }
        br.close();
        br = null;

        //Solve
        long[] V = new long[T];
        for(int t = 0; t < T; ++t){
            int n = N[t] - 1;
            V[t] = 3*nSum(n/3) + 5*nSum(n/5) - 15*nSum(n/15);
        }

        //Print
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int t = 0; t < T; sb.append(V[t++]).append("\n")){
        }
        System.out.print(sb);
    }

    public static long nSum(int n){
        long v = n;
        return (v*v + v) >> 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have an extra `{}` ?

Comment: Not part of the code.  If understanding how to enclose code, am to place between two brackets of {code goes here}

Comment: ok.. fixed. You need to select the code block  and press Ctrl + K

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem with a php code and I used return instead of echoing for your case replace sout with return

Comment: Java doesn't work that way. The compiler will emit a compiler error when you use a `return` where you shouldn't or don't use it where you should.

Comment: Okay I did not see the code well,though return can be used in methods in Java